# SwiftUI View adding @Environment(\.presentationMode) crashes .sheet() presentation

Tags: swiftui, environment, modalviewcontroller

I have view that uses .sheet() to present modally some another ChildView
I want to dismiss ParentView when this sheet is dismissed. So there is onDismiss callback.
However when I add

```
@Environment(\.presentationMode) var presentationMode
```

then presenting sheet it crashes with such bug

> libc++abi: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
> *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Application tried to present
> modally a view controller
> <*TtGC7SwiftUI29PresentationHostingControllerVS_7AnyView*:
> 0x7ffc07175c60> that is already being presented by
> <*TtGC7SwiftUI19UIHostingControllerGVS_15ModifiedContentVS_7AnyViewVS_12RootModifier*_:
> 0x7ffc04438c00>.' terminating with uncaught exception of type
> NSException CoreSimulator 757.5 - Device: iPhone 12 Pro
> (DEE900D2-F542-496C-9000-14498B9AA407) - Runtime: iOS 14.5 (18E182) -
> DeviceType: iPhone 12 Pro

Without using this environment property everything works ok.
It seems that sheet tries to present itself multiple times then this property is available.
But on other screens (views) everything works ok.

```
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000113b4ffba __exceptionPreprocess + 242
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x00000001136cdff5 objc_exception_throw + 48
    2   UIKitCore                           0x0000000121df4f32 -[UIViewController _presentViewController:withAnimationController:completion:] + 6016
    3   UIKitCore                           0x0000000121df593c __63-[UIViewController _presentViewController:animated:completion:]_block_invoke + 98
    4   UIKitCore                           0x0000000121e1049c -[_UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator _applyBlocks:releaseBlocks:] + 294
    5   UIKitCore                           0x0000000121e0c70e -[_UIViewControllerTransitionContext _runAlongsideCompletions] + 126
    6   UIKitCore                           0x0000000121e0c482 -[_UIViewControllerTransitionContext completeTransition:] + 106
    7   UIKitCore                           0x0000000122a2f3cc -[UITransitionView notifyDidCompleteTransition:] + 247
    8   UIKitCore                           0x0000000122a2f069 -[UITransitionView _didCompleteTransition:] + 1422
    9   UIKitCore                           0x0000000122a68e7a -[UIViewAnimationBlockDelegate _didEndBlockAnimation:finished:context:] + 779
    10  UIKitCore                           0x0000000122a39831 -[UIViewAnimationState sendDelegateAnimationDidStop:finished:] + 231
    11  UIKitCore                           0x0000000122a39dd6 -[UIViewAnimationState animationDidStop:finished:] + 263
    12  UIKitCore                           0x0000000122a39f57 -[UIViewAnimationState animationDidStop:finished:] + 648
    13  QuartzCore                          0x00000001122a8dc0 _ZN2CA5Layer23run_animation_callbacksEPv + 308
    14  libdispatch.dylib                   0x000000011ab8b74e _dispatch_client_callout + 8
    15  libdispatch.dylib                   0x000000011ab99b3f _dispatch_main_queue_callback_4CF + 1152
    16  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000113abd8f8 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_SERVICING_THE_MAIN_DISPATCH_QUEUE__ + 9
    17  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000113ab8169 __CFRunLoopRun + 2781
    18  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000113ab71a7 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 567
    19  GraphicsServices                    0x0000000121151d85 GSEventRunModal + 139
    20  UIKitCore                           0x000000012251d4df -[UIApplication _run] + 912
    21  UIKitCore                           0x000000012252239c UIApplicationMain + 101
    22  SwiftUI                             0x0000000115b15c36 $s7SwiftUI17KitRendererCommon33_ACC2C5639A7D76F611E170E831FCA491LLys5NeverOyXlXpFAESpySpys4Int8VGSgGXEfU_ + 119
    23  SwiftUI                             0x0000000115b15bbd $s7SwiftUI6runAppys5NeverOxAA0D0RzlF + 143
    24  SwiftUI                             0x0000000115652384 $s7SwiftUI3AppPAAE4mainyyFZ + 61
    25  Pro                                 0x0000000104d6bf40 $s3Pro0A3AppV5$mainyyFZ + 48
    26  Pro                                 0x0000000104d6bfd4 main + 20
    27  libdyld.dylib                       0x000000011ac19bbd start + 1
```

Sample code looks like this

```
struct ParentView: View { 

@Environment(\.presentationMode) var presentationMode


    var body: some View {
      mainButton 
    .sheet(
            item: $viewModel.item,
            onDismiss: {
               
            },
            content: { summary in
               ChildView()
            }
        )

}

}
```

Comment: You are not supposed the dismiss the parent view, only the sheet.

Comment: It crashes on presentation. It tries to appear 2 times

Comment: I only reacted to what you wrote.

Comment: Without a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) it is impossible to help you troubleshoot.

Comment: Minimal example is given above, but in minimal example it works ok I think it is related to nesting views inside hierarchy

Comment: By your own works it isn't a minimal reproducible example then... What is `viewModel`? What does `ChildView` look like? what is the point of `summary` if `ChildView` doesn't take it in as a parameter? If you are truly trying to dismiss `ParentView` how do you expect the `.sheet` to exist?

Comment: Ok I found solution. What was causing the problem was that when there is Environment(\.presentationMode) there is some refreshing done on this view 
.sheet(item:) relies on Identifiable type that requires id. 
It has this id but if it used optional identifier with like var id: String { myId ?? UUID().uuidString } 
When there wasn't this Environment this underlying model id doesn't change but with Environment property underlying item model has recalculated id and it was causing problem by trying to present this view double times.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I found solution. What was causing the problem was that when there is **Environment(.presentationMode)** there is some refreshing done on this view
.sheet(item:) relies on Identifiable type that requires id.
It has this id but if it used optional identifier with like

```
var id: String { myId ?? UUID().uuidString }
```

When there wasn't this **Environment** this underlying model id doesn't change but with Environment property underlying item model has recalculated id and it was causing problem by trying to present this view double times.